# Cocoapods points to wrong version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I had some problems with one version of the project. I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756433/pod-install-giving-error-on-xcode-7) where someone suggest steps to remove all cocoapods-connected stuff from the machine and reinstall it. I did follow the steps:

```
$ 'pod --version'
0.36.1

$ gem list --local | grep cocoapods
cocoapods (0.39.0.rc.1, 0.38.2, 0.38.1, 0.37.2)
cocoapods-core (0.39.0.rc.1, 0.38.2, 0.38.1, 0.37.2)
cocoapods-downloader (0.9.3, 0.9.1)
cocoapods-plugins (0.4.2)
cocoapods-search (0.1.0)
cocoapods-stats (0.6.2, 0.5.3)
cocoapods-trunk (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
cocoapods-try (0.5.1, 0.4.5)

$ gem uninstall cocoapods // and all others from the list above
```

The problem is that when i again grep all cocoapods, the list was equal to upper one, nothing disappeared.

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. cocoapods-0.37.2
 2. cocoapods-0.38.1
 3. cocoapods-0.38.2
 4. cocoapods-0.39.0.rc.1
 5. All versions
> 5

$ pod --version
// here was the error command not found, so everything fine

$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching: cocoapods-0.38.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.38.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.38.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.38.2
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

$ pod --version
Could not find proper version of cocoapods (0.36.1) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But why does it want me to install 0.36.1? Anyway, as it asked, I did:

```
$bundle install
Installing cocoapods-core 0.36.1
Installing cocoapods-downloader 0.8.1
Installing cocoapods-plugins 0.4.1
Installing cocoapods-trunk 0.6.0
Installing cocoapods-try 0.4.3
Installing cocoapods 0.36.1
// Many "using" dependencies
```

So now when I run:

```
$ pod --version
0.36.1
```

And I'm stuck :) Why can't I have newest release version? Maybe `pod --version` points to the newest version of `cocoapods-core` instead of only `cocoapods`, so everything is ok and I have the correct version?

Comment: I needed to downgrade cocoapods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487849/how-to-downgrade-or-install-an-older-version-of-cocoapods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems something got messed up in my ruby version. I still have no idea what and why. I've managed to fix it via this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25021772/849616. After it everything works correctly.

Comment: Try `bundle install` first, then you can run `pod install` again.

Answer (score 7):

- Check if you use Gemfile and there is specified the version of
  cocoapods.
- You can use specific version by `pod *version* action`. For example: `pod _1.5.0.beta.1_ update` or `pod _1.5.0.beta.1_ install`

Comment: This question is 3 years old and I don't remember the context. But looking at my accepted answer, which had to fix the issue, I rather claim it was a bug in some cache of ruby on my machine. Anyway, for most cases you have a good direction, it could be in a Gemfile (what suggests the output in console "Run `bundle install`"). But I don't think your 2nd point would work, if someone has a version specified in Gemfile he should update Gemfile. Installing specific version of cocoapods wouldn't help, because Gemfile would force the previous one. So, future reader, update cocopods version in Gemfile

Comment: Thanks for this answer; helped a lot. I didn't realize my Gemfile was looking for a specific (and older) version of Cocoapods. I deleted Gemfile.lock, reinstalled my pods, and it worked. Phew!

Comment: yes deleting Gemfile.lock and running "pod install" fix the problem.. atlast build fine. even pod --version was showing previous version although I had installed new cocoapod verion.. phew

Answer (score 5):

I ran `pod install` and  I've got this error:

```
Could not find proper version of cocoapods (1.11.3) in any of the sources
```

and I ran:

```
bundle install
```

after that `pod install` worked properly

Comment: I am getting this error when trying bundle install ```An error occurred while installing ffi
(1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.15.5'
--source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before
bundling```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming to this in an attempt to update cocoapods. After doing all of the above I wasn't able to get this resolved. I then headed to the resolved answer and being unwilling to remove RVM, I tried to resolve this issue another way.

I found that my issue did indeed lie in my Gemfile.

First, run 
`gem install cocoapods` to ensure you have the latest version, or whatever specified version you were looking for downloaded.

Second, ensure your projects Gemfile hasn't specified a cocoapods version number and instead simply specifies it as:
`gem "cocoapods"`
If yours doesn't, change this and run `bundle update` to regenerate the Gemfile.lock file and your problem should be solved. If not, go ahead and delete the Gemfile.lock file altogether and then run `bundle update`. You can easily check to see which gem version will be loaded by opening the Gemfile.lock file and searching for `cocoapods-core <version number here>`

At this point, you can go into your project and run 
`pod setup`
and then check the cocoapods version with 
`pod --version`

and now FINALLY you are free to run
`pod install` 
to replace the Podfile.lock file and get back to your happy dev life. Hope that helps someone and saves them from burning hours.

Answer (score 1):

You might face this issue when it comes migrating to a higher Swift version. Assuming that you already have cocoapods installed, you probably need to run **`bundle update`** command (possibly with `sudo`).

<sub>For more details, you could check: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html</sub>

Additionally, I'd suggest to do the following:

- Install the latest Xcode version.
- Clear derived data (not just clean project) in your project.
- Run `pod update` command.

Comment: Looking at the year, I guess the project was objective-c only, but I don't remember already. Surely all of the actions you wrote above did not help, I highly doubt I could not try those steps. Hope it helps someone else though :-)

Comment: @Vive I preferred to share it because I faced the issue and resolved it by doing what I mentioned. I agree with you, hope that someone else get the benefit of it 

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

In my project, `pod --version` and `gem which cocoapods` always return diffrence version.

All I had to do is remove Gemfile.lock in my project and `bundle install` again. It removed the locked cocoapods version and install a new one.

Hope that helps some one here.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the cocoapods version in the gem lock file is different than the one installed. You may have multiple installed.

Delete the cocoapod version using `gem uninstall cocoapods`

Then use `bundle update` to update your lock file to the correct version.

Then use `bundle install` if necessary to install it to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

1. rm -rf ~/.rvm
2. reopen terminal window
3. do the dance