# Cannot upgrade past CocoaPods 0.39.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods, rbenv

I am trying to upgrade to CocoaPods 1.2.1 but cannot uninstall CocoaPods 0.39.0.

I have reviewed numerous posts about this issue.  Evidently 0.39.0 caused a lot of problems.  I do not have enough reputation points to attach all the links I have reviewed but there are several StackOverFlow questions and GitHub Issues on the topic as v.0.39.0 evidently had some problems.  Here are two of the many posts I reviewed:

STACKOVERFLOW QUESTIONS:
[Cocoa Pods need to completely re-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016382/cocoa-pods-need-to-completely-re-install/25021772#25021772)

COCOAPODS BLOG POST ABOUT SHARDING and v.0.39.0:
http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/

Here is my 'gem env' output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.12
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: 
/Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/johndoe/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: 
/Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/johndoe/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
     - /Users/johndoe/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
```

And here is my 'gem list --local | grep cocoapods' output:

```
cocoapods (1.2.1)
cocoapods-core (1.2.1, 1.2.0, 0.39.0)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.1)
cocoapods-downloader (1.1.3, 0.9.3)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0, 0.4.2)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0, 0.1.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0, 0.6.2)
cocoapods-trunk (1.2.0, 0.6.4)
cocoapods-try (1.1.0, 0.5.1)
```

I have tried the following solutions:

1) "sudo gem uninstall cocoapods" then "sudo gem install cocoapods" and closed and reopened the terminal after each step

2) I modified my .bash_profile to make sure my echo $PATH includes the - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: from my gem env

3) Tried "gem pristine --all"

4) Made sure my home brew was up to date

5) Reinstalled rbenv

6) Tried various combinations of:

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/
$ sudo rm -fr Pods/
```

and then uninstalled and reinstalled cocoapods…

7) Manually applied “sudo gem uninstall” to each element in the output of my “gem list --local | grep cocoapods” and then …

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

8) Tried
    $ sudo gem update cocoapods

9) I tried:
    sudo gem install cocoapods:1.2.1

but when I try

```
pod _1.2.1_ version
```

or

```
pod —version
```

it says 0.39.0

10) The output of “which pod” is:
    /usr/local/bin/pod

11) I cannot recall if the first time I tried “sudo gem uninstall cocoapods” it gave me the option of specifically uninstalling 0.39.0.  I chose “All Versions” nevertheless

12) I tried “sudo chown -R "$(whoami)" /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv" to make sure it wasn’t a permissions issue

13) I am using Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!  Help!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

This was the only way I could get rid of 0.39.0 and install the latest version of CocoaPods...

I found this solution and an explanation for why this was a problem at the following link:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3736

Hooray!